# selecting specific lines repetitively from a file

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk

I have a file containing 20736 lines. Each 81 lines represent coordinates of atoms of a molecule. So I have total coordinates for 256 molecules.
Now I want to select coordinates for specific part of every single molecule. For example within the 81 lines I want to only select line 44 until 81 from each molecule until all 256 molecules.

To explain much detail, I want to select lines

```
44-81 from 1-81 lines
126-163 from 82-163 lines
208-245 from 164-245 lines
290-327 from 246-327 lines
and so on until 20736 lines
```

To achieve this, I have tried with bash script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash           

while read line           
do           
echo "$line"           

done < malto-thermo-RT.set30.traj.pdbL1
```

But I am not sure how to proceed with implementing a loop to select only lines 44 until 81 lines from every subsequent 81 lines of the file.

Appreciate I get some help.

I also wish to get solution in python,awk, and perl if can for learning purpose.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well start writing Python, we don't do it for you.

Comment: @sudo_O: Ok, I understand what's wrong: the 1st has to begin at `0`, because `163-82=81`, `245-164=81` also `81-0=81`, not `81-1`!!!

Comment: @vijay: Your example line ranges are inconsistent with your question. If you continue the examples until the 256th molecule, you'll have the range 20954-20991, but you claim there are only 20736 lines in the file.

Comment: Dear @rici, you are correct. I missed to mentioned about the line separator once every 81 lines in the file. Apologies for that.

Comment: @Vijay: Please correct your post: There could not be `20736` and `256` molecules and `81 + 1` lines + sep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{ ($f,$t)=(44,81) }
  ($.==$f .. $.==$t) =~ /(E0|.)$/ or next;
  print;
  $1 eq "E0" or next;
  $_ += 82 for $f,$t;
' file
```

Comment: Many thanks for this: I've read `man perlop` to understand your post (or `man -P'less +/\\.\\..*==' perlop`). But I've learn something today! ... Anyway using modulos, this could be written simplier: `perl -ne 'print if (($.%82)==44..($.%82)==81)'`

Comment: @F.Hauri you're right about modulos. As for `..`, it is an range operator. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Answer (score 3):

`m % n` (in many programming languages) is the "modulo" operator: the remainder which is left after all the largest possible integer multiple of `n` is removed from `m`.

The lines you want to print are those lines for which the line number modulo 81 is at least 43. (This works out better if the first line is counted as line 0; making that adjustment means you want lines numbered 43-80; 124-161; 205-242 etc. (I think the OP has a small arithmetic error, but it might be an explanation error. The sequence here is based on the stanzas being 81 lines, as the OP says, rather than 82 lines as the example seems to indicate).

So, in awk:

```
awk  '(NR-1)%81 >= 43'
```

That's based on awk's default action, which is `{print}`, so I didn't have to supply one.

**Edit**: If the example ranges provided in the OP are correct (which they would be if there were a blank line separating the 81-line stanzas, for example, then this could be changed to:

```
awk 'NR%82>43'
```

Comment: I don't think it's the OP arithmetic error. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19178113/1066031

Comment: @rici Care: the SO question is wrong: first step has to begin at `0` not `1`!

Comment: @F.Hauri: If that were true, there would be 82 lines per molecule; the question says 81. Also, the question says there are 20736 lines for 256 molecules, which is exactly 81 lines/molecule. That eliminates the possibility that there is a separator line, which would be consistent with the example ranges. So either the question is incorrect, or the example line ranges are incorrect. My solution works for the question, not the example line ranges. In any event, it's easy to fix given a consistent question.

Comment: @rici yes you are correct about the ambiguity. My assumption is that the lower ranges are more likely to be correct. This is also what the accepted answer does. Would be nice for clarification from the OP however

Comment: @sudo_O: yeah. Both are easy, anyway. I added the other one.

Comment: Dear @rici, I cant believe it. This short code can do amazing job. Thanks lot. I learnt new way for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my naive, non-idiomatic crack it it using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/tmp/file
segment_size=81
select_offset=44
select_size=37

start_line=$select_offset
end_line=$(($start_line + $select_size))

i=0
while read line
do
    i=$(($i + 1))
    if [ $i -ge $start_line ]; then

        [ $i -eq $start_line ] && [ $i != 1 ] && echo -e "\n-------------------\n"

        if [ $i -le $end_line ]; then
            echo "$line"

            if [ $i -eq $end_line ]; then
                start_line=$(($start_line + $segment_size + 1))
                end_line=$(($start_line + $select_size))
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < $file
```

Bash is certainly not my forte :\ :\ Seems to work tho!

Answer (score 1):

***Edited*** due to SO question's error.

Using modulos are surely the best way. The original idea in this SO question was added by @rici!

Unfortunely, the SO question is wrong: *...from 82-163 lines* (included), than *...from 164-245 lines*, I count **82** lines, not 81.

In first, I just would like to offer my [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `+` [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) alternative solution.

But now corrected, to better match the SO question, this could help to show where's the bug:

```
sed -nf <(for ((i=0;i<20736;i+=82));do echo $((i+44)),$(($i+81))p;done ) < file
```

Where bash generate sed commands and sed do the job.

**Splitted explanation**

The `bash` portion:

```
for ((i=0;i<20736;i+=82)) ;do
    echo $((i+44)),$(($i+81))p
  done
```

do

```
44,81p
126,163p
208,245p
290,327p
...
20544,20581p
20626,20663p
20708,20745p
```

> ( **Nota:** This match exactly the SO question sample, but don't end at 20736!!
>
> ```
>    echo $((20746000/82))
>    253000
> ```
>
> if it represent molecules, there is only 252 full molecules, in *20736* lines. )

So the `sed` script could by written:

```
sed -ne '44,81p;126,163p;208,245p;290,327p;...;20626,20663p;20708,20745p' <file
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple perl using @rici's idea of modulos:

```
perl -ne 'print if $.%82>43' file
```

Answer (score 1):

[**rici**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174141/1066031) has the right idea by using the modulus operator but as the records increase his solution progressively becomes out of sync as demonstrated by the following:

```
$ seq 350 | awk  '(NR-1)%81==43{printf "%i",$0} (NR-1)%81==80{print " -",$0}' 
44 - 81                         # In sync
125 - 162                       # Out of sync by 1 
206 - 243                       # Out of sync by 2 
287 - 324                       # Out of sync by 3
```

To print the lines you requested you would do:

```
$ awk 'NR%82>43' file
```

The printed ranges are:

```
$ seq 350 | awk  'NR%82==44{printf "%i",$0} NR%82==81{print " -",$0}'
44 - 81
126 - 163
208 - 245
290 - 327
```

Test yourself with:

```
$ seq 350 | awk  'NR%82>43'
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what's wrong: the 1st has to begin at `0`, because `163-82=81`, `245-164=81` also `81-0=81`, not `81-1`!!!

Comment: @sudo_O: See my response to F.Hauri in my solution. Annoying that you can't address a comment to two people.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem statement is fine but you haven't tried hard. Check how a combination of `head` and `tail` commands & how to pass parameters to your script can help you achieve what you want.

http://www.ss64.com/bash/head.html
http://www.ss64.com/bash/tail.html

For example,

```
$ cat file
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```

In this example, we can print lines from 3 to 7 using:

```
$ head -7 file | tail -5
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

Comment: If someone is downvoting, i think he/she should also spare some time to let me know why it was done so that i can improve on it.

Comment: This probably was down-voted because your solution is look at the `head` command. Can you suggest how the `head` command would help here?

Comment: @sudo_O: Thanks for pointing my mistake. I should have mentioned a combination of 'head' and 'tail' commands; i only mentioned one. I'll correct it.

Comment: How would you head and tail to print multiple ranges across a file though?

Comment: If we already have the ranges, can't we pass them as arguments and process them in groups of two (min and max)? Few more lines will be required to implement that i guess.

Comment: First you would have to calculate the ranges which you would do on the fly and then just print those lines. I really don't think calculating all the ranges then calling `head` and `tail` for each record is a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

Using `awk`, you can do some like this

```
awk '
    {
    if (NR<=t) 
        {
        for (l=t-37;l<=t;l++) 
            printf "%s ",$l
        }
    if (NR==t)
        {
        t+=82
        }
    } ' t=81 file
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But when I run, I do not any output. The screen seems to be blank only until finish runnig.

Comment: Can you try now? it some difficult when we do not have the file.

Comment: @jotne beside being the wrong approach your answer has lots of mistakes. If you want an input file to test using `seq` to generate a list in of ints.

Comment: I did have an `a` extra, used to test, removed.  Logic is ok. Line `1` gives field `44-81`, line `2` field `44-81` and so to line `81`, then line `82 to 163` print filed `126 to 163` etc

Comment: The OP doesn't ask to split fields he just wants lines 44-81, 126,163, ect printed.